# What is the meaning of ripple voltage? and How to calculate a rectifier capacitor?

Tags: voltage-regulator, charger, circuit-design

What is ripple voltage?

I think it is the voltage difference of the two red arrows... Is that correct?

[image]

[image]

My second question: If I need to use a voltage regulator [LM7805CV](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/CD00000444-249828.pdf). What would be the value of smoothing capacitor?

The application is a cell phone charger. It uses a bulk transformer. The output of the transformer is connected to a rectifier circuit then a voltage regulator.
I need the final output of the charger to be 5v and the ripples are less than 10mV.

Thank you very much,

Comment: There is no such thing as "5v exactly without ripples". You need to specify how low the ripple really needs to be. Less than 10 mV? less than 1 mV? less than 100 uV? Any lower than that and you're getting into "heroic efforts" territory. You should also specify your operating current, and the frequency range of variations in the current drawn by the load.

Comment: @ThePhoton I need the ripples to be less than 10mV.

Comment: To find the ripple of the rectifier you need to know the current load.

Comment: @ThePhoton I do not know the actual load current. It is a cell phone: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_pocket_s5300-4612.php

Also I need to use  LM7805CV as a voltage regulator. Does the equation that I provided in this question works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure 30 in your LM7805 datasheet shows an input voltage rejection ratio of about 75 dB around 50 or 60 Hz. That means that you "should" only need to maintain an input ripple below 50 V to keep output ripple below 10 mV. Meaning you should have little issue achieving 10 mV ripple.

Realistically you should probably choose some target input ripple for your regulator (maybe 100 mV), and then choose your rectifier capacitor using that target and the formula in your question.

Comment: The frequency of my country = 50 Hz. Should I use it? or Should I use 100 Hz which is the output frequency of the four diode (rectifier) stage?

Comment: Yes if you use a full-wave rectifier, the *f* in your equation will be 2x the mains frequency.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this .They are all approximations based on assumptions .If we assume that the phone could draw up to 1 Amp when charging and your proposed 7805 reg rejects ripple as long as the valley of the rectified AC is above 8V .Looking at your graph which is valid one can say that the cap is being charged for 2mS and discharged for 8mS .This assumes 50HZ full wave rectifier giving half cycles of 10mS total .If we ballpark a gross ripple of 2V pkpk then we need 4000 microfarads .Normal aluminium electrolytic caps have bad tolerances and can lose capacitance with age .This is why these calcs are often ballparked .The difference between 50 and 60 Hz is in the same ballpark as cap tolerances.Always choose the preferred value above your calc .Choose 4700 microfarad .